# Can we use encryption/decryption for audio file in android

Tags: java, android

I already did encryption and decryption of an audio file which I want to protect. But after doing decryption it shows some Warning Logs for MediaPlayer, and MediaPlayer is also not working.

So I just wanted to know whether the encryption /decryption process has corrupted my audio file?

Logs are mentioned here:

```
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFFC
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at com.zenagestudios.itaaleemlehra.LessonPlayActivity.startPlayer(LessonPlayActivity.java:293)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at com.zenagestudios.itaaleemlehra.LessonPlayActivity.onClick(LessonPlayActivity.java:446)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2461)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8890)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-14 13:41:42.136: W/System.err(17602):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried the same code for encryption/decryption for a sample XML file and it's working fine for the XML file.

Here is the code I have used for encryption/decryption:

```
 public void encrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out){
    try {
        // Bytes written to out will be encrypted
        out = new CipherOutputStream(out, ecipher);

        // Read in the cleartext bytes and write to out to encrypt
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0){
            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        System.out.println("Database Encrypted");
        out.close();
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


 public void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out){

    try {
        //staticdata. dialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "","Loading. Please wait...", false);
        // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
        in = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);

        // Read in the decrypted bytes and write the cleartext to out
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {

            out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
        }
        System.out.println("Database Decrypted");

        out.close();
    } 
    catch (java.io.IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? MediaPlayer is stateful and the error seems to indicate a state problem are you sure it is related to the encryption?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems you don't encrypt/decrypt the file correctly. You can test your encryption/decryption on a simple text file to see yourself if the file stays intact.

Comment: i have tried the same code of encryption and decryption for some xml file and it working fine.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I cannot help :(

Comment: i Just wanted to know the surety for this, that does encryption/decryption really effects media quality or its data?

Comment: Encrypting and then decrypting should not change anything, even a single byte.